# Apache CacheIgnoreURLSessionIdentifiers to ignore select query string params

Tags: apache2, cache, httpd

I am looking for a way of specifying a list of query parameters that I want to ignore for caching.

Can I use the directive `CacheIgnoreURLSessionIdentifiers` to ignore select query parameters regardless of whether they are used for session identifiers?

> This causes cachable resources to be stored separately for each
>   session, which is often not desired. CacheIgnoreURLSessionIdentifiers
>   lets define a list of identifiers that are removed from the key that
>   is used to identify an entity in the cache, such that cachable
>   resources are not stored separately for each session.

Comment: AFAIK `CacheIgnoreURLSessionIdentifiers` doesn't _prevent_ caching, but rather ignores the specified query string params when a resource is cached. So, if you specified `foo` and `bar` then `/index.php?foo=1&bar=2` would be cached under the key `/index.php` - it's still cached.

Comment: ... or maybe that is what you require? You do still want the resource cached? ...mod_cache - server-side caching module.

Comment: @w3dk Thats what I want....want to ignore querystring parameters. I guess my question really is should CacheIgnoreURLSessionIdentifiers really be called CacheIgnoreQueryStringParameters as its not specific to session identifiers?

Comment: At least [according to the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html#cacheignoreurlsessionidentifiers), `CacheIgnoreURLSessionIdentifiers` does seem to apply to _any_ query string params you specify. You'll have to try it. :) Why it makes such close reference to session identifiers I'm not sure, except that maybe session identifiers are probably it's most common usage.

Answer (score 2):

#### Short version

**Yes**, you can use the directive `CacheIgnoreURLSessionIdentifiers` to ignore any query parameter for caching purposes (e.g. `fbclid`).

Just make sure that all URLs behind the cache behave the same, regardless of the existence and the value of the parameter. Else the cache might deliver wrong content.

#### Long version

The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache.html#cacheignoreurlsessionidentifiers) only mentions session identifiers as an use case but states

> CacheIgnoreURLSessionIdentifiers lets define a list of identifiers that are removed from the key that is used to identify an entity in the cache, such that cacheable resources are not stored separately for each session.

The implementation in [`modules/cache/cache_storage.c`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/cache/cache_storage.c#L563) checks two cases:

```c
/*
 * Check that we have a parameter separator in the last segment
 * of the path and that the parameter matches our identifier
 */
```

meaning that `;theidentifier=foobar` is removed from the cache key, if there is such a parameter at the end of the path (and before the query string).

**and**

```c
/*
 * Check if the identifier is in the query string and cut it out.
 */
```

meaning that `theidentifier=foobar` is removed from the query string part of the cache key. The code also does clean cutting, so that no trailing `&` or `?` is left. As a result the cache handles a request for `/index.html?theidentifier=foobar` exactly like a request for `/index.html`.